# Canvas lms bundle exec rails db:initial_setup error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, database, rubygems, canvas-lms

I am trying to install canvas lms on Debian but in the step called "Database population" (here is a tutorial: (https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start) when I use a command `bundle exec rails db:initial_setup` i get the error like this:

```
/var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:308:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated digest 3.1.0, but your Gemfile requires digest 3.1.1. Since digest is a default gem, you can either remove your dependency on it or try updating to a newer version of bundler that supports digest as a default gem. (Gem::LoadError)
        from /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:25:in `block in setup'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:155:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:155:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:24:in `map'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:24:in `setup'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler.rb:161:in `setup'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:136:in `with_level'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/ui/shell.rb:88:in `silence'
        from /var/lib/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
```

From this output I understand that I should have version 3.1.1 but my is 3.1.0
In this tutorial is the same version as mine (3.1.0). Have someone this problem? I am trying to resolve it for couple of days but without any results...

I've tried using this:
bundle clean --force
deleting the *config/dynamic_settings.yml* file

Comment: Did you try updating bundler, as the error suggests?

Comment: Yes, but there is nothing to update as I get an output in console
"Updating installed gems
Nothing to update"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered some similar problems before
which telling me "You have already activated xxx a.b.c, but your Gemfile requires digest a.d.e.

that happens frequently during developing, seems like canvas use a lot of default gems which are older than the ones come with ruby

> and in your case, seems like you have to upgrade bundler first

bundler need X gem of version1, but you activate X of version2

execute `bundle update xxx` to upgrade that gem

but sometimes this won't do the trick because it's a default gem, and the bundler require an older version

you have to remove the default gem of that version to force bundler use the required one

for example, I encountered problem which says

```bash
You have already activated json 2.6.3, but your Gemfile requires digest 2.6.1.
```

and after executing `bundle update json`, I found out that won't help

you have to remove the json-2.6.3 in your gem path

> you can find the path by `gem environment` and find the `GEM PATHS:`

I installed ruby with asdf, so I found and deleted the gem which located at `$HOME/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/specifications/default/json-2.6.3`

but make sure you backup that default gem in another path if something happens